# Более плавная анимация перемещения в android studio

Tags: java, android, анимация

Как усовершенствовать код?

По экрану движутся кнопки (от 5 до 12), движение задается через xml для каждой кнопки индвидуально.

```
<set android:ordering="sequentially"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="5000"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="1820"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:propertyName="y"
            android:repeatCount="4"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="5000"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="910"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:propertyName="X"
            android:repeatCount="4"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
    </set>
</set>
```

после нажатия на кнопку, она летит на другие координаты:

```
        set1.end();
        ObjectAnimator moveX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pr1, "x", ListCoordinateX.get(0) );
        ObjectAnimator moveY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pr1, "y", 60 );
        AnimatorSet as1 = new AnimatorSet();
        as1.playTogether(moveX, moveY);
        as1.setDuration(4000);
        as1.start();
        ListCoordinateX.remove(0);
```

Но летит она "не красиво" - сначала улетает на свою  финальную точку по координатам из .xml и только потом движется на новую позицию. Как можно реализовать более плавное перемещение, что бы оно осуществлялось с той позиции, где кнопка была нажата?

Comment: зачем вам xml? В коде все правильно, она и полетит в координаты которые вы задаете сразу. y=60 не ошибка?

Comment: Она изначально двигается по координатам из xml, до тех пор пока на неё не нажмут. А вот когда нажмут - тогда появляются новые координаты. И мне нужна плавность смены хода

Comment: можно назначить новые координаты и установить Interpolator Linear

Comment: Если вы делаете анимацию через xml, то кнопка по факту не меняет координаты, а лишь движется в заданную сторону визуально. Из чего следует, что после окончания анимации кнопка вернётся в исходное состояние.

Comment: @Mr.Krotos это не так, меняет.

Comment: вам нужно сначала отменить предыдущую анимацию, и еще я ошибся, конечно же Accelerate Interpolator для плавности

Comment: Разве? Я пробовал использовать. Может что-то все же делал не так. Извините за дезинформацию.